# How to call the local image file and display into the imageviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, asihttprequest

I create the one application in that create the locally store the file in payment while the application not be deleted.

This I have done: I download the file and store into locally (applications document folder).

Now I am having trouble with this:
While the after the image is downloaded then I fetch into locally and that image will not display. In NSLog following url is generated and i can't display the image.

> /Users/username/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/F233ED88-1546-4FB0-BE93-0E0FB8C8C3D6/Documents/NationalMedalofArts-150x150.jpg

**Edit:**

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                   @"/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/F233ED88-1546-4FB0-BE93-0E0FB8C8C3D6/Documents/NationalMedalofArts-150x150.jpg"]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
self.imgView.image = image;
```

when the NSLog the NSData then it's NULL to display

Comment: What have you tried, have you got any error-logs, could you explain a bit further? This is a very vague question and hard to answer.

Comment: Complete the URL as that string looks like a path, not an URL. I mean URLs begin with "http:" or "file:" or something, your string is only a path of a file in local file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is better:

```
NSString *fileName = @"NationalMedalofArts-150x150.jpg";
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(), fileName];
self.imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: It's shorter, but that doesn't make it better :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* file = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NationalMedalofArts-150x150.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:file];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
self.imgView.image = image;
```

When accessing files in the documents-folder of the application, which is where images and those sorts of things are found, you must use the first line to find the path to the documents-folder. The code above should work for you.